# jquery add onmouseover attribute

Tags: jquery, mouseover

in jquery, how do I add an 'onmouseover' event to an element.

eg

```
<tr id=row bgcolor=white>
```

becomes

```
 <tr id=row bgcolor=white onMouseOver="this.bgColor='red'">
```

Comment: why do you want to add the inline attribute? You can just use the `.mouseover()` event in jQuery

Comment: i have several rows, row_1, row_2, etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `attr` method:

```
$('#row').attr("onMouseOver", "this.bgColor='red'")
```

But since you are using jQuery I'd recommend using the `on` method:

```
$('#row').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: +1 for first answering the question, then pointing out the ideal way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

try this if the element is static:

```
var $row = $('#row');
$row.mouseover(function(){
    $row.css('background-color','red');
});
```

use this if the element is dynamically placed in the page:

```
var $row = $('#row');
$row.on('mouseover',function(){
    $row.css('background-color','red');
});
```

Comment: Those two variations do exactly the same thing.  If you want a delegated event handler to cater for dynamically added elements you need to use a different syntax of .on() - see the doco.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the attribute. Use the event.

```
$('#row').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css('background','red');
});
```